# ASP.NET PostBack on selecting checkbox of treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, postback

I have an asp.net project and working in C#.

In my project I have a databound listbox that has checkboxes.

When the user clicks on a checkbox it should for an example update a label/textbox.

The thing is, it doesnt update the label/textbox until I click on a button that does a postback. How will I Call a postback on the checkbox changed event, since the "OnTreeNodeCheckChanged" event looks like it only fires once the postback has been triggered?
Is this even a good idea (to want to call a postback every time the a checkbox has been changed)

--Updated code Snippet--
Asp

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="treevCourses" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ShowCheckBoxes="All" Width="100%"
                OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="check_changed" Height="16px" ImageSet="Contacts">
```

(Tried having the handler in the C# part.)
C#

```
protected void check_changed(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {
        lblTest.Text = "TestText";
        }
```

(Also tried having it in the script part)

```
void check_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTest.Text = "TestText";
    }
```

Binding data to the Treeview (this happens on a button postback)

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(row["courseName"].ToString(), row["courseName"].ToString());
                    //  node.PopulateOnDemand = true;
                    treevCourses.Nodes.Add(node);
                }


                //select from topic where parentId = topicId.
                ds = myConClass.returnSqlDataset("select cd.courseName,ct.[date] from courseDetails cd join courseTimes ct on cd.courseId = ct.courseId");

                foreach (TreeNode treenode in treevCourses.Nodes)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        if (row["courseName"].ToString() == treenode.Value)
                        {
                            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(row["date"].ToString(), row["date"].ToString());
                            treenode.ChildNodes.Add(node);
                        }
                    }       
                }
```

Comment: Give me the brief Description ......

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that

Comment: can you update question with relevant code?

Comment: where you bind data to TreeView?

Comment: I've added the answer that you've marked as correct first btw. Damith basically just copied what I've posted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no `AutoPostBack` property on TreeView. And as per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.ontreenodecheckchanged.aspx), The `TreeNodeCheckChanged` event is raised when a check box in the `TreeView` control changes state between posts to the server

You need to do something else, like mentioned on [this link](http://forums.asp.net/post/3995882.aspx)

1) Add  on click attribute to TreeView1 on page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TreeView1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "postBackByObject()");
}
```

2) add java script function and do the post back

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     function postBackByObject()
     {
         var o = window.event.srcElement;
         if (o.tagName == "INPUT" && o.type == "checkbox")
        {
           __doPostBack("","");
        } 
    }
   </script>
```

3). Implement `TreeNodeCheckChanged` event

```
protected void TreeView1_TreeNodeCheckChanged(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
```

Comment: O.o That worked... Thank you.
Its weird that in JavaScript I cant seem to find window.event (theres only window.eval and window.escape) still a major beginner with this so might pick this up somewhere, so thanks for the help man, This worked Perfectly.

Comment: post back using java script affect the update panel.update panel not work suppose if i want partial postback.

Comment: 3). Implement TreeNodeCheckChanged event - add OnTreeNodeCheckChanged on asp:TreeView
(In case any other newbie like me is struggling)

Answer (score 1):

When you're dynamically binding the TreeView the `TreeNodeCheckChanged` event will not be fired when you click the checkbox, you can overcome this quite easily though with a little bit of javascript:

**ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fireCheckChanged() {
            var o = window.event.srcElement;
            if (o.tagName == "INPUT" && o.type == "checkbox") {
                __doPostBack("", "");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TreeView ID="treevCourses" runat="server" 
            ShowCheckBoxes="Parent,Leaf" Width="100%" Height="16px" ImageSet="Contacts" 
            ontreenodecheckchanged="check_changed" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var data = new XmlDataSource();
        data.DataFile = Server.MapPath("~/input.xml");
        treevCourses.DataSource = data;
        treevCourses.DataBind();

        treevCourses.Attributes.Add("onclick", "fireCheckChanged()");
    }
}

protected void check_changed(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    string clickedNode = e.Node.Text;
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

*Is this a good idea* - Obviously sending requests to the server everytime the checkbox state is changed can become resource intensive but if you cannot replicate the same functionality using javascript then this is your only option

Comment: it doesn't work... It does a post back when you click on the one of the nodes, but not when you click a checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
treevCourses.Attributes.Add("onclick", "fireCheckChanged()");
```

with

```
treevCourses.Attributes.Add("onclick", "fireCheckChanged(event)");
```

and  replace the script with

```
  function fireCheckChanged(e) {
 var evnt = ((window.event) ? (event) : (e));
 var element = evnt.srcElement || evnt.target;

 if (element.tagName == "INPUT" && element.type == "checkbox") {
      __doPostBack("", "");
}}
```