# Checked Change event of tree view is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am working with `Treeview` control and I am using the following code

```
  <asp:TreeView ID="tvCategories" ShowCheckBox="False" Style="font-family: Trebuchet MS;
                                    margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-left: 20px; color: Black; font-size: 12px"
                                    runat="server" ShowLines="true" NodeIndent="5" OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="tvCategories_TreeNodeCheckChanged"
                                    OnSelectedNodeChanged="tvCategories_SelectedNodeChanged">
                                    <LeafNodeStyle ForeColor="#555555" />
                                    <ParentNodeStyle ForeColor="Black" />
                                    <RootNodeStyle ForeColor="Black" />
                                </asp:TreeView>
```

Both the `OnTreeNodeCheckChanged` and `OnSelectedNodeChanged` are not working and the `AutoPostBack` property is not available for `Treeview`.

Please help me out with this issue. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `AutoPostBack` property for TreeView.

As per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.ontreenodecheckchanged.aspx):

*The `TreeNodeCheckChanged` event is raised when a check box in the `TreeView` control changes state between posts to the server. This allows you to provide an event-handling method that performs a custom routine, such as updating a database or the displayed content, whenever this event occurs.*

You can try javascript to postback the page by adding the onclick event.

Reference: [PostBack on selecting checkbox of treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15946006)

Comment: thanks @vishal i want to store a `session` on `TreeNodeCheckChanged` is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: @GarimaRawat This is the only method. I have posted a link above through which you can store the session inside `TreeView1_TreeNodeCheckChanged` event which will be called once the postback happen.

Answer (score 5):

You need use javascript to make the page postback, then the treenodecheckchanged event can be fired.

like below, you should add the code of bolder to make the page postback.:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function postBack()
 {
     var element = window.event.srcElement;
     if (element .tagName == "INPUT" && element.type == "checkbox")
     {
        __doPostBack("","");
     } 
 }

</script>
```

Add the above javascript code in the head section of the page.

```
onclick="javascript:postBack()"
```

Comment: sorry for not marked as answer your question.but i had up-vote your question and appreciate it :)

Comment: that is so sweet of you saying sorry but its ok and thanks @GarimaRawat :)

Comment: Even better, you can use `__doPostBack('<%= this.myUpdatePanel.UniqueID %>', "")` to get a nice partial postback on your UpdatePanel